# Add new row in horizontal linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am creating dynamically images in linear layout with horizontal orientation. I am using:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new 
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200,200));
            imageView.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
            imageView.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
            setImageIcon(imageView, ap.getPackageName());
            topLayout.addView(imageView);
```

But at the end of the screen it continues to add icons in infinity on the right side. I somehow want to add border and start in new line.Is there any option that i can do that? Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/master_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:columnWidth="320dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:rowCount="8"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_droptarget_grey"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text_top"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="40dp"
              android:clickable="false"
              android:text="Security upgrade avaliable"
              android:textAlignment="center"
              android:textSize="28dp"/>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_droptarget_green"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text_bottom"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="40dp"
              android:clickable="false"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:text="Secured Apps"
              android:textAlignment="center"
              android:textSize="28dp"/>

</LinearLayout>


</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It cannot be done with linear layout. If you set orientation to horizontal in will never go to new line.
You can decide on how many views you want to be allowed in your layout and then always check like this if you exceed this count just add another linearlayout below to imitate a new line to your topLayout and start adding to the new layout but it's a workaround

```
int childCount = ((ViewGroup)linearLayout).getChildCount();
```

A cleaner solution would be to use GridLayout as it is. You can also add images dynamically there and mark the maximum of elements in a row without using LinearLyout. The code below means you will have 2 elements in a row and as many rows as you put. And you can use `add` method to add ImageViews.

```
GridLayout mLayout = new GridLayout(0,2);
```

Another solution would be a version of FlowLayout. Check out this [git example](https://github.com/nex3z/FlowLayout)